# <wheel user> is not in sudoers file for NetBSD 7.0

Tags: permissions, sudo, netbsd

I installed `sudo` on NetBSD 7.0 using `pkg`. I copied `/usr/pkg/etc/sudoers` to `/etc/sudoers` because the docs say [`/etc/sudoers` and possibly `/etc/sudoers.local` is used](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sudoers+5). I uncommented the line `wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`. I then added myself to the `wheel` group. I verified I am in `wheel` with `groups`. I then logged off and then back on.

When I attempt to run `sudo <command>`, I get the standard:

```
jwalton is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported
```

What is wrong with my `sudo` installation, and how can I fix it?

Comment: isn't it `%wheel` for a group?

Comment: @Alex - good catch - I think the odd key mappings from OS X to the VM and emacs caused the deletion of the leading `%`. I re-added it, but still encounter the problem. Let me try to add myself to `staff` next (I tried to add myself to `sudo` but it results in an error *`can't append group 'sudo' for user 'jwalton'`*).

Comment: Try adding yourself to the `%sudo` group too, `usermod -G sudo jwalton`

Comment: @Alex - the command `usermod -G sudo jwalton` failed with the message `can't append group 'sudo' for user 'jwalton'`.

Comment: Then you don't have enough privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo(8) as installed by pkgsrc is configured to look in /usr/pkg/etc/sudoers. It will not look at /etc/sudoers.

If you're updating your access control via visudo(8), it should be modifying the correct file.  If you're not updating the sudoers file via visudo(8), please start doing so.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Are you certain about *"/usr/pkg/etc/sudoers"*? The docs state otherwise. Unfortunately for *" ...if you're not updating the sudoers file via visudo(8), please start doing so..."*, I don't use vi; rather, I use emacs. I know its pretty much a religious debate, but I learned emacs in college 20 years ago, so I don't want to learn another editor.

Comment: The documentation on a NetBSD system is going to override anything else on the 'net.  Read the manual pages on NetBSD to learn how any software will work on NetBSD.

Comment: visudo is a wrapper around $EDITOR or $VISUAL, so will use your favorite editor.  Part of visudo's functionality is to validate the format of the sudoers file, so you really want to use it (much as you would use vipw to edit/validate the master.passwd file.)

Comment: OK, thanks. The location of the sudoers file was the problem. Its unfortunate that SEO hijackers have manged to supplant [NetBSD project as the source of the information](http://www.google.com/search?q=netbsd+sudoers).

Comment: Note that someone removed the forced setting of `sysconfdir` during configuration to `/etc` (thus defaulting it to `$PKG_SYSCONFDIR`, which does default to `/usr/pkg/etc`, _but_ it is often customized), but the same patch does not fix any references in the manual pages, so strictly speaking both the linked manual page in the original post, and the actual manual page in any pkgsrc installation, will in fact refer only ever to `/etc/sudoers`.  Personally I think forcing `sysconfdir` to match the documentation is better than changing it and leaving the documentation wrong as was done.

Comment: Also note:  the link to the referenced documentation in the original post _is_ the link to the _official_ manual page for third-party software for NetBSD.